# Easiest way to convert list to a comma separated string by a Specific Property?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a list of Custom objects ,Actually those are entities I am storing in an IEnumerable collection. I want to convert the list  to a comma separated string, but  I want only one specific property,  How do I build a comma separated string with a specific property from a custom object list?

I know i can build a comma separated list by using a `"Foreach / For (int i .... "` 
but I think there is a easy and a better way for this 
So what would be that easy way?

This is my list

```
IEnumerable<BAL.Category> categories = chklCategories.CheckedItems.Cast<BAL.Category>();
            //Category object has a property called Name , I want the list from that property
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is very easy , Isn't it ?

```
string sCategories = string.Join(",", categories.Select(x => x.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this.

By using this version of the `string.Join<string>` method, you can reduce copies of your collection before joining.

```
static string CombineList(IEnumerable categories)
{
  return string.Join<string>(",", categories.Select(x => x.Name));
}
```